# unable to connect with soap based wcf service from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, soap, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to consume a SOAP web service from my iPhone application but I am getting following error when I check with Charles:

**Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s**

Following is my code:

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><SOAP-ENV:Body><updateTimesheet><TimeSheetHourID>222</TimeSheetHourID></updateTimesheet></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://172.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx/postService.svc/basic"];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
NSLog(@"Message Length..%@",msgLength);

[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"urn:IpostService/updateTimesheet" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
//NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Response Code: %d", [urlResponse statusCode]);
if ([urlResponse statusCode] >= 200 && [urlResponse statusCode] < 300) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", result);
    //here you get the response 
}
```

I am getting error code 500 in response. Can some one please help me?

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: Try dumping the raw request data to the console. Then use something like SoapUI to test the request and find what's wrong: http://www.soapui.org/

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 is -  Internal Server Error. Which means - 
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Make sure you are sending proper request to your server. Are you able to consume it somewhere else?

Comment: yes I have just checked it on wcf test client and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not with your code here .. i advise you to trace the webservice code.

Comment: I have checked the service on wcf test client and it works fine there